# WampServer Install with website and database

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have a linux dedicated server that has a php / mysql site and database on it.  I am trying to figure out if there is a way to create an install of wamp server on a windows pc that will include the files for that site and it's associated database.

I would like to use this almost like an installable program for a windows pc.

Here is the situation... I have a site that was built for the U.S. Trampoline and Tumbling Association.  It allows the insertion of USTA Meets, Clubs, Athletes and allows USTA Clubs to generate a Meet Entry Form when they want to attend a specific USTA Meet.  All this works wonderfully on the website.

At any particular USTA Meet... a reliable internet connection is not always available... so I am thinking that if I can do an install of Wamp Server that includes the site and database and then sync the database just prior to the meet... I can give them the great functionality of the site on their own local computer with current info from the site itself without needing to have an internet connection.

Can anyone tell me of a way to package a wamp server install with the site files and database to use it for a current local version of the site that is online?

Not sure if I will be able to create a automated script to update the database info or not... but can handle that manually via support team if necessary.

THANKS!!